# grid for data entry

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, wpf-controls

As part of a WPF presentation, I need a control like the mock up below to let a user:

1. enter a variable number of percentages up to 100%
2. know what the total of all entries are
3. know what the balance is (100% - TotalEntered)

While this is obviously a pretty pedestrian requirement, I am at a loss as to how to implement it. It's a one-off requirement, so it need not be a reuseable, although it would be nice if it could be. A pattern to allow separation and testability (ie, MVVM) would also be great.

I assume the existing DataGrid control is the right tool to go with, but maybe it's overkill. Can someone suggest some starting implementation code or link to same?

Cheers,
Berryl

[image: mock up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM = "ViewModel" implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Create a `Shares` VM and a `Share` VM (implementation removed for brevity).

```
SharesViewModel
{
    double TotalPercent
    double RemainingPercent
    ObservableCollection<ShareViewModel> Shares
    // foreach Share in Shares 
    //   handle PropertyChanged on ActualPercent to update TotalPercent
}
ShareViewModel
{
    int Line
    string Percent // on set, parse/validate and set ActualPercent
    double ActualPercent
}
```

Use this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid) to see how to keep the `Line` sequence in order.

Bind `DataGrid ItemsSource` to `SharesViewModel Shares` property.

(Ensure to validate percent inputs. `IDataErrorInfo` may help.)